# How to force a method to be called

Tags: php

I am creating an API, and I have a class called `Service` which has a function `requireType()`

`$type` is one of `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` or `DELETE`

```
final public function requireType($type){
    // Do some stuff
}
```

I also have a master class called `API` it creates an instance of the class called from the `API` lets call it `ClassA` which then extends `Service`.

```
class ClassA extends Service{

    // Writer called "$this->requireType()" method is fine to run
    public function myAction(){
        // Make sure $this->requireType() was called here before anything else gets run
        $this->requireType("POST");
        // Do some stuff
    }

    // Writer did not call "$this->requireType()" method
    // An error should occur
    public function myAction(){
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

What I would like to know, is in my `API` class how (if possible) can I check to see if `requireType()` is getting called right away in `myAction()`?

The API class method call looks something like this (simplified):

```
// This method creates an instance of "ClassA" and runs "myAction()"
// We should check to see if the person who wrote the method "myAction()" 
// called "$this->requireType()" or not. If not throw an Error
final public function execServiceRequest($clientData = ""){
    $class = $this->getService();
    $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($class, $this->action);
    $obj = new $class();
    $obj->setReadWrite($this->read, $this->write);
    $obj->initPage($this->config);
    $obj->setData($clientData);
    $obj->before();
    $response = call_user_func(array($obj, $this->action));
    $obj->after();
}
```

So in the end I would like something like this:

The client from `example.com` sends a `PUT` request to `api.example2.com`, `api.example2com` knows what the client sent. The method that gets called does not know, it needs to say if you are going to call me you need to send a `GET` request and if you don't you need to send a different request with a `GET` header in order to access this method.

I mostly want to add this feature so a developer that is creating new methods doesn't write code that will accept any one of the 4 header types by accident.

Comment: Well... th.. what? could you add a comment at the line where you would like to know wether or not `requireType()` was called?

Comment: Basically I just want to make sure that the person writing new public methods in a class that extends `Service` starts the method with a call to `$this->requireType()`

Answer (score 1):

I would put the constructor in the `Service` class:

```
class Service {
  final public function __construct($type) {
    $this->requireType($type);
  }
}
```

that way, any class extending from service will have to be constructed with a `$type` and will call the function

Or, if it is important that each call to `myAction()`has a different type, you can have an abstract method and a defined method in your `Service` class:

```
abstract class Service {
  final public function myAction($type) {
    $this->requireType($type);
    $this->customAction();
  }
  protected function customAction();
}
```

that way, everyone calls `myAction()` with their desired type (enforced by php) then `myAction()` calls `customAction()` which has to be defined in the extending class

Comment: `$type` is different for each method.

Comment: that is why you pass it as a parameter to the class extending service.

Comment: That won't work `MethodA` could require `POST` while `MethodB` could require `GET` if you pass it through the constructor you can't create it for each method.

Comment: this smells of design problem... if it is mandatory for them to call requireType before using any function, most probably you should rethink your classes? are you using interfaces? abstract classes? How come it is mandatory to call requireType but it is not clear enough that they have to manage it?

Comment: Okay maybe this will make it more clear: The client `example.com` sends a `PUT` request to `api.example2.com` `api` knows what the client sent the method needs to say if you are going to call me you need to sent a `GET` request, not a `PUT` request. Try again.

Comment: So basically I just want to force the developer to not forget that they need to add that at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 0):

In the base controller constructor, set an instance variable called "calledRequireType" to false.

In requireType, set calledRequireType to true.

In... whatever code you want to check if they called it (presumably the same handler that calls xxAction, after calling xxAction), check calledRequireType and throw an exception.

Comment: they will be writing the functions in which the check would happen, not op :)

Comment: In that case put the calledRequireType in the base class they are extending. I'll update my answer